# Eisenstein Criterion Shift Conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I have been working through my Abstract Algebra book and have come across Eisenstein's criterion.  Many of the problems have been proving polynomials are irreducible using a shift in Eisenstein's criterion.  That is, give some $f(x)$, let $f(x+b)=g(x)$ for which we can use Eisenstein's criterion on $g(x)$ to prove that $f(x)$ is irreducible.

I understand the conditions and the proof. However,

> I was wondering if any irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ can be shifted to $g(x)=f(ax+b)$ then use Eisenstein's criterion on $g(x)$?

I was researching some of this and came across the following:

Let $f(x)$ be monic with integer coefficients and let $g(x)=f(ax+b)$ for integers $a$ and $b$. Suppose there exists a prime $p$ for which Eisenstein applies to $g(x)$. Then $f(x)$ is irreducible. Now show that such an $a$ and $b$ exists if and only if $g(x)=c(x-b)^n\pmod p$ for some $c$. The hint was to use Taylor expansions. I have been working on this problem for a while and just cannot seem to figure out how to go about proving the if and only if statement.

Please provide hints. Not answers. Thanks!

Comment: The claim you've written down is false. It doesn't include the extra condition in Eisenstein's criterion about $p^2$ not dividing the constant term. Anyway, hint for a corrected version of the statement: if $g(x) = f(ax + b)$, what is $f(x)$ in terms of $g(x)$?

Answer (score 9):

Good question! The answer is no, but it's surprisingly hard to produce either an explanation why or a counterexample without introducing some algebraic number theory.

The short story, which is still not so short, is that if $f(x)$ is, say, a monic integer polynomial of degree $n$, we can associate to it an integer $\Delta$ called the [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant_of_an_algebraic_number_field) of the number field it generates, and if Eisenstein's criterion works for a prime $p$ on $f(x)$ or any translate of it (we can set $a = 1$ without loss of generality), then $p^{n-1}$ must divide $\Delta$, and it's possible to write down examples of cubic polynomials $f(x)$ (so that $n-1 = 2$) such that $\Delta$ is squarefree.

The long story involves a concept in algebraic number theory called [ramification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramification#In_algebraic_number_theory). See [this PDF](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/totram.pdf) for some details, although you might need to crack open a textbook on algebraic number theory first.

In particular, from Wikipedia I learn that if $f(x) = x^3 - x^2 - 2x - 8$ then the discriminant is $-503$, which is the negative of a prime, so Eisenstein's criterion cannot be used on any translate of $f$.

Comment: Thank you! I have not taken an algebraic number theory class but hope to next semester so maybe I will just look into it now. I appreciate the explanation!

Comment: I have a quick question. As I was going through the logic, it all made sense to me except the following: the counter example from wikipedia, we get that the discriminat is -503 for which no prime (except for itself) can divide it. I get that $p^{n-1}$ must also divide the discriminant to be able to use Eisenstiens criterion, but how do we know that we cannot shift it and change the discriminant to be one that satisfies the conditions? Are there simply properties of the discriminant of shifted polynomials that I am missing for this?

Comment: @user: the discriminant doesn't change when you shift the polynomial. It only depends on the number field generated by the roots.